# Maven can't resolve the Kotlin Maven Plugin jar

Tags: java, maven

Not sure how to fix this.

I want [this version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.2-M2) of the Kotlin runtime and [maven plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-maven-plugin/1.2-M2).

These are the bits in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-M2</version>
    </dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-M2</version>
            <executions>
```

And I added this as a repo:

```
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>kotlin-bintray</id>
        <name>Kotlin Bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/</url>
    </repository>
```

I get this error:

> Failure to find
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:jar:1.2-M2 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are
>   forced

But I don't see anything that might be wrong.

By the way, notice that the runtime jar is found, so the repository section must be correct since this repository is where maven finds it. The maven plugin jar is a different matter for some reason though...

Comment: Just FYI, it seems that this jar is in maven central (no need for the `repository` section) - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-maven-plugin/1.2-M2

Comment: @DanW it's not there, there is even a comment indicating where the repo is

Comment: (I need this specific version, even though other version exist in the maven central)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just fixed. It was something really silly. I found out that for plugins one needs to define a plugin repository section.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>kotlin-bintray</id>
        <name>Kotlin Bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And now it works. I guess I should spend more time learning maven in depth :)

Comment: OK, I didn't see that it's in a 3rd party repo, I've updated my answer even though you've fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

i just added this line and it worked for me
`<version>${kotlin.version}</version>`

Answer (score 4):

To make sure it downloads fresh from maven central you will need to blow away your local copy, so delete the directory:

~/.m2/repo/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-maven-plugin

You will also need to add the 3rd party repo to your settings.xml at ~/.m2 [see here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

```
<settings>
 ...
 <profiles>
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
   ...
 </profiles>
 
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
 ...
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html), we can see how to implement Compiler Plugins

For `kotlin-allopen` add the followin `<configuration>` and `<pluginOptions>` inside the `<plugin>` tag

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <!-- Or "spring" for the Spring support -->
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>

        <pluginOptions>
            <!-- Each annotation is placed on its own line -->
            <option>all-open:annotation=com.my.Annotation</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=com.their.AnotherAnnotation</option>
        </pluginOptions>
    </configuration>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```